# How can I create popup windows?

Tags: scripts, cron, git

I have a small script run by cronjobs to synchronize a git repository every 2 hours. The git will be pushed to the server with a constant message. How can I have a popup windows which ask the message before the changes will be committed? So I will get a popup windows every 2 hours and I just have to enter a short description that what I have modified on the code.

Comment: Would have thought Zenity is ideal for that, or have I missed what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) command like this might help

```
zenity --entry --text "Enter short description:" --entry-text=""
```

Command returns your short description so you need to work that into your cronjob